# Add sort by category in product listing Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I've tried to find a possible solution for this but without any result I need to display a sort by category field in the default Magento toolbar in product listing page. Does anyone know how to add this feature without messing up my core files?

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is something Magento calls Layered Navigation.

First you must make a parant category Apparel and one (ore more) child categories, for example: 
- shirts
- shoes 
- hoodies

Then for all the child categories go to the admin back-end and navigate to:
Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Display settings.

Now make sure you set the field "Is Anchor" to yes.
Apply this setting for all the children categories.

After these steps your front-end product-listing should look like:
http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalog/category/view/s/apparel/id/18/

At the left sidebar you can see the categories that are children of the parent category Apparel. Of course you can use your own names for the diffrent categories.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes I know about layered navigation. But it displays only immediate sub categories. If i wanted to add another sub category to the child category then it won't display the whole tree of that main category. I want to display child as well as child of child until there are no categories left. You could say i want to traverse the whole tree in all branches until each branch has reached its leaf node.